# Check if a radiobutton is not checked in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Basically I'm trying to set the disabled attribute to a select node when the checkbox labeled as Section is not checked, if it is checked it should remove the attribute.

HTML:

```
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="table" value="main_categories" checked>
        Section</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="table" id="subcat" value="sub_categories">
        Catégorie</label>
    <select id="selectsec">
        <option value="1">Test</option>
    </select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subcat').change(function(){
        if (!$('#subcat').is(":checked")) {
            $('#selectsec').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#selectsec').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason this isn't working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your event won't fire on de-selection, you need to apply the event to all of your radio buttons (we can use your `name` attribute):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/czmmepeu/1/)

```
$('input:radio[name=table]').change(function() {
    if (!$('#subcat').is(":checked")) {
        $('#selectsec').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#selectsec').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Turismo98 No problems glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').click(function() {
   if($('#subcat').is(':checked')) {
            $('#selectsec').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
   }
   else {
            $('#selectsec').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9ud9zvL9/)

EDIT: It also will work if you selected an different radio button on your page. Put your radio buttons into a div and change

```
$('input').click(function()
```

to

```
$('#idOfyouDiv').click(function()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `change` event doesn't fire on the un-checking of a radio input; therefore you have to bind the `change` event-handler to the group of `<input />` elements and check whether `this` has the `id` of the element you're looking to check, for example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // binding the change event-handler to all <input> elements
  // whose type is 'radio' and whose name is 'table':
  $('input[type=radio][name=table]').on('change', function() {
    // this will be the <input> that *is* checked, so
    // we test whether subcat is checked by checking the id
    // of this changed <input> element:
    var subcatChecked = this.id === 'subcat';

    // setting the disabled property of the <select> element
    // to true (when subcat is not checked) or false (when
    // subcat is checked):
    $('#selectsec').prop('disabled', !subcatChecked);
  });
// triggering the change event-handler on page-load/document-ready:
}).filter('#subcat').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="table" value="main_categories" checked>Section
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="table" id="subcat" value="sub_categories">Catégorie
</label>
<select id="selectsec">
  <option value="1">Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if (!$('input[name=table]:checked').val() ) 
{
alert("Not Checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkOpt = function(){
        if ($('[name$=table]:checked').val() == 'main_categories') {
            $('#selectsec').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#selectsec').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    };
    $('[name$=table]').change(checkOpt);
    checkOpt();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkdrhvk6/1/

Note: This also ensure the select is correctly enabled/disabled when the page first loads.